# Leetcode : AddressSanitizer heap-buffer-overflow

Tags: c

I am practicing the Leetcode question "Next Greater Node in Linked List" 
and here is my code:

```
#define STACK_SIZE (10000U)

typedef struct ListNode Node;

static int stack[STACK_SIZE];
static int top=-1;

bool isEmpty()
{
    return (top==-1);
}

void addToStack(int element)
{
    stack[++top]=element;
}

void remFromStack()
{
    --top;    
}

int getStackTop()
{
    return stack[top];
}

 typedef struct ListNode Node;

 int* nextLargerNodes(struct ListNode* head, int* returnSize) {

        if (head == NULL) {

            *returnSize = 0;
            return NULL;
        }

        int len = 0;
        Node *temp = head;

        while (temp) {
            len++;
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        if (len > 0) {
            int *result = malloc(len * sizeof(int));
            *returnSize = len;

            if (result == NULL) {
                return NULL;
            }

            int j = 0;
            while (j < len) {
                result[j++] = 0;
            }

            temp = head;
            addToStack(temp->val);
            j = 0;
            while (temp->next) {
                temp = temp->next;
                j++;

                if (getStackTop() > temp->val) {
                    addToStack(temp->val);
                } else {
                    int i = 0;
                    while (!isEmpty()) {
                        i++;
                        result[j - i] = temp->val;
                        remFromStack();
                    }
                    addToStack(temp->val);
                }
            }
            return result;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }

}
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
=================================================================
==29==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x6030000
WRITE of size 4 at 0x60300000000c thread T0
 #2 0x7f55143382e0 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.s
0x60300000000c is located 4 bytes to the left of 20-byte region [0x60300
allocated by thread T0 here:
 #0 0x7f55157c22b0 in malloc (/usr/local/lib64/libasan.so.5+0xe82b0)
 #3 0x7f55143382e0 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.s
```

I am not sure what's wrong here.

Tried making sure all the code is correct, and when I test the code against my own test cases, it works perfectly fine, but when I submit the code, only then I am getting this error.

Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().

The utility functions dont have any malloc/ calloc called in them, so, that removes them from the equation.

Comment: You didn't provide all the code, but it sounds like `result[j - i] = temp->val;` is accessing memory you didn't allocate, probably because `i` is greater than `j` (so you are accessing `result[-1]`)

Comment: Check your `isEmpty()` and `remFromStack()` functions.

Comment: but the AddressSanitizer is pointing towards malloc.

Comment: @mnistic . I have added all the code now.

Comment: Unrelated: Get rid of *`if (len > 0)`* when execution gets there `len` is always `> 0`.

Comment: What is your test case?

Comment: Tried all there: 
[2,1,3,1,5],
[2,7,5,1],
[7,5,1],
[1,5,7],
[0],
[]

Comment: It is failing for some test cases - not getting the expected answers, that's fine, I will correct the code. 
But what I do not understand is why I am getting this error in the first place.

Comment: `remFromStack()` is decrementing `top` without checking its value, but I don't think that's the problem here. Other than that, I don't see anything else...

Comment: Maybe their environment is in some weird state?

Comment: Probably yes. Because in one of the other problems I saw, that when I use 'sizeof' operator for a string, it gave me another AddressSanitizer error, but when I used the 'strlen' for that same string, it worked like a charm.

Comment: sizeof operator doesn't work on strings, as strings are char*. A char* is a pointer with a particular size of its own. sizeof will return the size of the pointer (8 bytes usually), not the size of the memory being pointed to. strlen is used to point to null-terminated strings. That said, if you pass leetcode a non-null-terminated string, there could be an overflow in the solution checker. I just ran into that, which is how I found myself here. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sizeof behaves differently on Leetcode.

Try to use strlen (if you are using char) OR other methods to find the size of a datatype you are trying to use.